# Symbol's function definition is void: rtags-enable-standard-keybinding

Tags: init-file, ctags, rtags

I have just started using emacs and I wanted to setup RTags.

Looking at the Usage section int the github repo [here](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags/wiki/Usage), I added the following line to my config

```
(rtags-enable-standard-keybindings c-mode-base-map "\C-xr")
```

On starting emacs I get the following error

> Symbol's function definition is void:rtags-enable-standard-keybindings

I searched for configs and all of them seem to use the same.

My configs are as follows

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/user/emacs_packages/neotree")
(require 'neotree)
(global-set-key [f8] 'neotree-toggle)


(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'company-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'company-mode)
(setq company-idle-delay 0)
(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)

(setq rtags-completions-enabled t)
(eval-after-load 'company
  '(add-to-list
    'company-backends 'company-rtags))

(setq rtags-autostart-diagnostics t)
(rtags-enable-standard-keybindings)
(rtags-enable-standard-keybindings c-mode-base-map "\C-xr")
```

Comment: There are [a *lot* of questions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=function+definition+is+void) that are essentially duplicates of this. Someone (TM) should give them some love by closing most as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

So I added the following lines to the config

```
(add-to-list 'load-path ".emacs.d/elpa/rtags-20190820.502/")
(require 'rtags)
```

and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means the function is not defined.  In order for it to be defined you have to ensure the file defining it is loaded.  This is classicaly done by something like `(require 'rtags)`.

Indeed, the minimal init.el configuration mentionned in the link you provided does include it:

> This minimal init.el configuration should be enough to get completion to work.
>
> (require 'package)
>
> (package-initialize)
>
> (require 'rtags)
>
> ...

From elisp [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html#Named-Features):

> ‘provide’ and ‘require’ are an alternative to ‘autoload’ for loading
>   files automatically.  They work in terms of named “features”.
>   Autoloading is triggered by calling a specific function, but a feature
>   is loaded the first time another program asks for it by name.
>
> A feature name is a symbol that stands for a collection of functions,
>   variables, etc.  The file that defines them should “provide” the
>   feature.  Another program that uses them may ensure they are defined by
>   “requiring” the feature.  This loads the file of definitions if it
>   hasn’t been loaded already.

Comment: Maybe the name symbol is not defined and that's why when I add the path and then user require, it works.